# Import of data set using read.table where data is uneven

Tags: r, file, import, read.table

I took the mtcars data set from MASS and made a few modifications. After going from one package to another I finally got the data into notepad where I carefully made sure that spaces were the delimiter. My problem is that the file thus created will not read in. I have a test file which reads in just fine.

Can you explain what the error message is telling me? Thank you. Error messages and code used is given below.

```
TEST.txt
120 140 7.5
140 150 8.5

mtcars2=read.table(file="TEST.txt",header=FALSE)
mtcars2
#    V1  V2  V3
# 1 120 140 7.5
# 2 140 150 8.5  OK
```

mtcars2.txt  problem dataset

```
160 110 2.62
160 110 2.875
160 110 2.32
160 110 3.215
160 115 3.44

mtcars2=read.table("c:\\data\\mtcars2.txt",header=FALSE)
```

> Warning messages: 1: In read.table("c:\data\mtcars2.txt", header =
>   FALSE) :   line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls ... 6: In
>   scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
>   embedded nul(s) found in input   NOT OK

I also tried the following:

```
mtcars2=read.table("c:\\data\\mtcars2.txt",fill=T,header=FALSE)
```

Comment: I can not re-create your problem. I do get a warning: incomplete final line.. but it still reads just fine. I copied your `mtcars2.txt` onto notepad and saved, then used your `read.table...` above and it more or less worked for me. I would go and see if you have any whitespace *behind* each of your lines the `.txt.` files.

Comment: Copying and pasting your data works fine for me, though you may have weird Unicode invisible characters in your data. Also, assuming you meant that dataset worked fine, you should move the "OK", as that _would_ create a problem for `read.table`.

Comment: unicode text was used along the way as i  converted from one package to another. What worked for me was to copy my data set, paste it into the question box on stackoverflow, copy pasted data and put into a new notepad file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used cut/paste and it works fine. I then put a null just before the first space and I got:

```
line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls.
```

I suspect you modified the file such that the values you output are like `'c' strings` with terminating zeros; or `Unicode (16 bit)` would also give trouble because it has zeros.
One thing you can do to check the contents of every byte in the file is to use UNIX/Linux `od` program:

```
od -c filename
```

sample output:

```
0000000000     1   6  \0  \0       1   1  \0       2   .   6   2  \r  \n   1
0000000020     6  \0       1   1  \0       2   .   8   7   5  \r  \n   1   6
0000000040    \0       1   1  \0       2   .   3   2  \r  \n   1   6  \0
```

Comment: I use windows mostly. What are you seeing in the sample output above. What indicates extra characters?  160 looks like 1600?

Comment: I modified by adding nul which shows as '\0' in a few places, digits appear as digits. The top row, for example shows as: "16<nul><nul><sp>11<nul> 2.62<cr><lf> 1" If you print to the terminal <nul> doesn't show.

Comment: interesting approach. I wonder if windows has an equivalent program?

Answer (score 0):

```
> dss <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
+ 160    110    2.62
+ 160    110    2.875
+ 160    110    2.32
+ 160    110    3.215
+ 160    115    3.44
+ ')
> dss
  X160 X110 X2.62
1  160  110 2.875
2  160  110 2.320
3  160  110 3.215
4  160  115 3.440
>
```

header=TRUE may be removed.